# Configuring Apache for Symfony

Tags: php, apache, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and Apache 2.4 (on Ubuntu); and I'm trying to get my Symfony project running through Apache instead of the built-in server. I edited the default  .conf file in the "sites-available" folder to the following:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my_project/web
<Directory /var/www/html/my_project/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from All
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

When trying any route, all i get is a "requested URL not found" error. Simply going to "localhost"takes me to app.php, which obviously does nothing. I've always restarted apache after every edit. What am i missing (besides a brain)?

Comment: Have you enabled the rewrite module ?

sudo a2enmod rewrite

Comment: Read a Symfony doc a bit... https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Here's a little [article](http://dancostinel.com/blog/how-to-create-php-development-environment-in-linux-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: I believe the error you mentioned is an Apache error. Have you checked your Apache error_log file?

Comment: I enabled rewrite, but now I just get a blank screen for all routes

Comment: did you add site to apache? `a2ensite yoursite.com.conf`

Comment: where is virtual host server name or server alias and which URL are you browsing?

Answer (score 1):

If you use composer (which is default for Symfony projects), you can just do `composer require symfony/apache-pack`, which should install default working .htaccess file into your `public` directory.